# NGINX gives Err 500 or 504 when using Organizr for Auth requests?

Tags: php, nginx, reverse-proxy, plex, auth-request

I'm currently setting up NGINX to use with my home media server and allow me to connect to my dPVR's such as radarr and sonarr via [organizr](https://github.com/causefx/Organizr). The problem I am experiencing is that upon adding auth-request to each of my location blocks for these services so that they are all behind organizrs authentication all the sites either give error 500, 504 or attempt loading some assets but returning 504 on the majority despite being configured as the examples suggest it should be. The host server is running windows 2012R2 with Nginx 1.12.2 and php-7.1.10. my nginx.conf file is as follows;

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

log_format upstreamlog '[$time_local] $remote_addr - $remote_user - $server_name  to: $upstream_addr: $request upstream_response_time $upstream_response_time msec $msec request_time $request_time';

sendfile        on;
keepalive_timeout  65;

upstream sonarr-upstream        { server 127.0.0.1:8989; }
upstream plexpy-upstream        { server 127.0.0.1:8181; }
upstream deluge-upstream        { server 127.0.0.1:8112; }
upstream radarr-upstream        { server 127.0.0.1:7878; }
upstream jackett-upstream       { server 127.0.0.1:9117; }

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  homeserv.mydomain.me 192.168.1.134;

    error_log c:/nginx/logs/www.error.log info;
    access_log c:/nginx/logs/www.access.log;

    set $return $request_uri;
    set $return_host $host;

    proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    proxy_connect_timeout      90s;
    proxy_send_timeout         90s;
    proxy_read_timeout         90s;

    proxy_buffer_size          4k;
    proxy_buffers              4 32k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;

    gzip on;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_min_length 1000;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain text/html text/css text/xml application/xml text/javascript application/x-javascript image/svg+xml;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";

    root   c:/nginx/html/organizr;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;

    error_page 400 401 403 404 405 408 500 502 503 504  http://homeserv.mydomain.me/error.php?error=$status;

    #pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 60s;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location = /auth-admin {
        internal;
        proxy_pass http://homeserv.mydomain.me/auth.php?admin;
        proxy_pass_request_body off;
        proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
        proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
    }

    location = /auth-user {
        rewrite ^ /auth.php?user;
    }

    location ~\.(json|db|log|)$ {
        return 404;
    }

    ##############
    # Reverse Proxies
    ##############

    location /radarr {
        auth_request /auth-admin;
        proxy_pass http://radarr-upstream; 
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        access_log c:/nginx/logs/access.log upstreamlog;
    }

    location /sonarr {
        auth_request /auth-admin;
        proxy_pass http://sonarr-upstream; 
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        access_log c:/nginx/logs/access.log upstreamlog;
    }

    location /plexpy {
        auth_request /auth-admin;
        proxy_pass http://plexpy-upstream; 
        proxy_redirect http:// $scheme://;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host    $server_name;
        access_log c:/nginx/logs/access.log upstreamlog;
    }

    location /deluge {  
        auth_request /auth-admin;
        proxy_pass http://deluge-upstream/; 
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Deluge-Base   "/deluge/";
        add_header              X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
        access_log c:/nginx/logs/access.log upstreamlog;
    }

    location /jackett {
        auth_request /auth-admin;
        proxy_pass http://jackett-upstream/;            
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        access_log c:/nginx/logs/access.log upstreamlog;
    }


    #deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    #concurs with nginx's one

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }
}

# HTTPS server
#
#server {
#    listen       443 ssl;
#    server_name  localhost;

#    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
#    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

#    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
#    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

#    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
#    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

#    location / {
#        root   html;
#        index  index.html index.htm;
#    }
#}
}
```

Having taken a look in my error log there is the same error over and over about upstreams timing out or unexpected auth responses, I'll also include my php and access logs. the upstream log at the bottom also suggests its hitting the 90s Proxy timeout? If anybody can suggest what is breaking this it would be fantastic!

```
2017/11/08 17:30:10 [error] 8732#8740: *3 upstream timed out (10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.1.134, server: homeserv.mydomain.me, request: "GET /ajax.php?a=get-calendar HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "192.168.1.134", referrer: "http://192.168.1.134/homepage.php"
2017/11/08 17:31:10 [error] 8732#8740: *3 upstream timed out (10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.1.134, server: homeserv.mydomain.me, request: "GET /ajax.php?a=get-calendar HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "192.168.1.134", referrer: "http://192.168.1.134/homepage.php"
2017/11/08 17:31:25 [error] 8732#8740: *11 upstream timed out (10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: homeserv.mydomain.me, request: "GET /sonarr/api/calendar?start=2017-10-09&end=2017-12-08 HTTP/1.1", subrequest: "/auth-admin", upstream: "http://5.*.*.130:80/auth.php?admin", host: "localhost"
2017/11/08 17:31:25 [error] 8732#8740: *11 auth request unexpected status: 302 while sending to client, client: 127.0.0.1, server: homeserv.mydomain.me, request: "GET /sonarr/api/calendar?start=2017-10-09&end=2017-12-08 HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2017/11/08 17:31:39 [error] 8732#8740: *2 upstream timed out (10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.1.134, server: homeserv.mydomain.me, request: "GET /radarr HTTP/1.1", subrequest: "/auth-admin", upstream: "http://5.*.*.130:80/auth.php?admin", host: "192.168.1.134", referrer: "http://192.168.1.134/"
2017/11/08 17:31:39 [error] 8732#8740: *2 auth request unexpected status: 302 while sending to client, client: 192.168.1.134, server: homeserv.mydomain.me, request: "GET /radarr HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.1.134", referrer: "http://192.168.1.134/"
2017/11/08 17:32:10 [error] 8732#8740: *3 upstream timed out (10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.1.134, server: homeserv.mydomain.me, request: "GET /ajax.php?a=get-calendar HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "192.168.1.134", referrer: "http://192.168.1.134/homepage.php"
2017/11/08 17:32:55 [error] 8732#8740: *15 upstream timed out (10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: homeserv.mydomain.me, request: "GET /sonarr/api/calendar?start=2017-10-09&end=2017-12-08 HTTP/1.1", subrequest: "/auth-admin", upstream: "http://5.*.*.130:80/auth.php?admin", host: "localhost"
2017/11/08 17:32:55 [error] 8732#8740: *15 auth request unexpected status: 302 while sending to client, client: 127.0.0.1, server: homeserv.mydomain.me, request: "GET /sonarr/api/calendar?start=2017-10-09&end=2017-12-08 HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2017/11/08 17:33:10 [error] 8732#8740: *3 upstream timed out (10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.1.134, server: homeserv.mydomain.me, request: "GET /ajax.php?a=get-calendar HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "192.168.1.134", referrer: "http://192.168.1.134/homepage.php"
2017/11/08 17:33:34 [error] 8732#8740: *18 upstream timed out (10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.1.134, server: homeserv.mydomain.me, request: "GET /sonarr HTTP/1.1", subrequest: "/auth-admin", upstream: "http://5.*.*.130:80/auth.php?admin", host: "192.168.1.134", referrer: "http://192.168.1.134/"
2017/11/08 17:33:34 [error] 8732#8740: *18 auth request unexpected status: 302 while sending to client, client: 192.168.1.134, server: homeserv.mydomain.me, request: "GET /sonarr HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.1.134", referrer: "http://192.168.1.134/"
2017/11/08 17:34:10 [error] 8732#8740: *3 upstream timed out (10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.1.134, server: homeserv.mydomain.me, request: "GET /ajax.php?a=get-calendar HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "192.168.1.134", referrer: "http://192.168.1.134/homepage.php"
2017/11/08 17:34:26 [error] 8732#8740: *21 upstream timed out (10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: homeserv.mydomain.me, request: "GET /sonarr/api/calendar?start=2017-10-09&end=2017-12-08 HTTP/1.1", subrequest: "/auth-admin", upstream: "http://5.*.*.130:80/auth.php?admin", host: "localhost"
2017/11/08 17:34:26 [error] 8732#8740: *21 auth request unexpected status: 302 while sending to client, client: 127.0.0.1, server: homeserv.mydomain.me, request: "GET /sonarr/api/calendar?start=2017-10-09&end=2017-12-08 HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2017/11/08 17:35:10 [error] 8732#8740: *3 upstream timed out (10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.1.134, server: homeserv.mydomain.me, request: "GET /ajax.php?a=get-calendar HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "192.168.1.134", referrer: "http://192.168.1.134/homepage.php"
2017/11/08 17:35:28 [error] 8732#8740: *24 upstream timed out (10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.1.134, server: homeserv.mydomain.me, request: "GET /jackett HTTP/1.1", subrequest: "/auth-admin", upstream: "http://5.*.*.130:80/auth.php?admin", host: "192.168.1.134", referrer: "http://192.168.1.134/"
2017/11/08 17:35:28 [error] 8732#8740: *24 auth request unexpected status: 302 while sending to client, client: 192.168.1.134, server: homeserv.mydomain.me, request: "GET /jackett HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.1.134", referrer: "http://192.168.1.134/"
2017/11/08 17:35:56 [error] 8732#8740: *26 upstream timed out (10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: homeserv.mydomain.me, request: "GET /sonarr/api/calendar?start=2017-10-09&end=2017-12-08 HTTP/1.1", subrequest: "/auth-admin", upstream: "http://5.*.*.130:80/auth.php?admin", host: "localhost"
2017/11/08 17:35:56 [error] 8732#8740: *26 auth request unexpected status: 302 while sending to client, client: 127.0.0.1, server: homeserv.mydomain.me, request: "GET /sonarr/api/calendar?start=2017-10-09&end=2017-12-08 HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2017/11/08 17:36:10 [error] 8732#8740: *3 upstream timed out (10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.1.134, server: homeserv.mydomain.me, request: "GET /ajax.php?a=get-calendar HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "192.168.1.134", referrer: "http://192.168.1.134/homepage.php"
2017/11/08 17:37:10 [error] 8732#8740: *3 upstream timed out (10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.1.134, server: homeserv.mydomain.me, request: "GET /ajax.php?a=get-calendar HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "192.168.1.134", referrer: "http://192.168.1.134/homepage.php"
2017/11/08 17:37:26 [error] 8732#8740: *30 upstream timed out (10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: homeserv.mydomain.me, request: "GET /sonarr/api/calendar?start=2017-10-09&end=2017-12-08 HTTP/1.1", subrequest: "/auth-admin", upstream: "http://5.*.*.130:80/auth.php?admin", host: "localhost"
2017/11/08 17:37:26 [error] 8732#8740: *30 auth request unexpected status: 302 while sending to client, client: 127.0.0.1, server: homeserv.mydomain.me, request: "GET /sonarr/api/calendar?start=2017-10-09&end=2017-12-08 HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2017/11/08 17:38:10 [error] 8732#8740: *36 upstream timed out (10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.1.134, server: homeserv.mydomain.me, request: "GET /ajax.php?a=get-calendar HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "192.168.1.134", referrer: "http://192.168.1.134/homepage.php"
2017/11/08 17:38:28 [error] 8732#8740: *36 upstream timed out (10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.1.134, server: homeserv.mydomain.me, request: "GET /settings.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "192.168.1.134", referrer: "http://192.168.1.134/"
2017/11/08 17:38:41 [error] 8732#8740: *3 upstream timed out (10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.1.134, server: homeserv.mydomain.me, request: "GET /deluge HTTP/1.1", subrequest: "/auth-admin", upstream: "http://5.*.*.130:80/auth.php?admin", host: "192.168.1.134", referrer: "http://192.168.1.134/"
2017/11/08 17:38:41 [error] 8732#8740: *3 auth request unexpected status: 302 while sending to client, client: 192.168.1.134, server: homeserv.mydomain.me, request: "GET /deluge HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.1.134", referrer: "http://192.168.1.134/"
2017/11/08 17:38:57 [error] 8732#8740: *34 upstream timed out (10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: homeserv.mydomain.me, request: "GET /sonarr/api/calendar?start=2017-10-09&end=2017-12-08 HTTP/1.1", subrequest: "/auth-admin", upstream: "http://5.*.*.130:80/auth.php?admin", host: "localhost"
2017/11/08 17:38:57 [error] 8732#8740: *34 auth request unexpected status: 302 while sending to client, client: 127.0.0.1, server: homeserv.mydomain.me, request: "GET /sonarr/api/calendar?start=2017-10-09&end=2017-12-08 HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2017/11/08 17:39:10 [error] 8732#8740: *36 upstream timed out (10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.1.134, server: homeserv.mydomain.me, request: "GET /ajax.php?a=get-calendar HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "192.168.1.134", referrer: "http://192.168.1.134/homepage.php"
2017/11/08 17:40:10 [error] 8732#8740: *36 upstream timed out (10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.1.134, server: homeserv.mydomain.me, request: "GET /ajax.php?a=get-calendar HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "192.168.1.134", referrer: "http://192.168.1.134/homepage.php"
2017/11/08 17:40:27 [error] 8732#8740: *40 upstream timed out (10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: homeserv.mydomain.me, request: "GET /sonarr/api/calendar?start=2017-10-09&end=2017-12-08 HTTP/1.1", subrequest: "/auth-admin", upstream: "http://5.*.*.130:80/auth.php?admin", host: "localhost"
2017/11/08 17:40:27 [error] 8732#8740: *40 auth request unexpected status: 302 while sending to client, client: 127.0.0.1, server: homeserv.mydomain.me, request: "GET /sonarr/api/calendar?start=2017-10-09&end=2017-12-08 HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2017/11/08 17:41:10 [error] 8732#8740: *36 upstream timed out (10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.1.134, server: homeserv.mydomain.me, request: "GET /ajax.php?a=get-calendar HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "192.168.1.134", referrer: "http://192.168.1.134/homepage.php"
2017/11/08 17:41:57 [error] 8732#8740: *43 upstream timed out (10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: homeserv.mydomain.me, request: "GET /sonarr/api/calendar?start=2017-10-09&end=2017-12-08 HTTP/1.1", subrequest: "/auth-admin", upstream: "http://5.*.*.130:80/auth.php?admin", host: "localhost"
2017/11/08 17:41:57 [error] 8732#8740: *43 auth request unexpected status: 302 while sending to client, client: 127.0.0.1, server: homeserv.mydomain.me, request: "GET /sonarr/api/calendar?start=2017-10-09&end=2017-12-08 HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2017/11/08 17:42:11 [error] 8732#8740: *36 upstream timed out (10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.1.134, server: homeserv.mydomain.me, request: "GET /ajax.php?a=get-calendar HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "192.168.1.134", referrer: "http://192.168.1.134/homepage.php"
```

PHP log:

```
[08-Nov-2017 17:31:25 Europe/London] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\nginx\html\organizr\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 509
[08-Nov-2017 17:32:55 Europe/London] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\nginx\html\organizr\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 509
[08-Nov-2017 17:34:26 Europe/London] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\nginx\html\organizr\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 509
[08-Nov-2017 17:35:56 Europe/London] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\nginx\html\organizr\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 509
[08-Nov-2017 17:37:26 Europe/London] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\nginx\html\organizr\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 509
[08-Nov-2017 17:38:57 Europe/London] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\nginx\html\organizr\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 509
[08-Nov-2017 17:40:27 Europe/London] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\nginx\html\organizr\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 509
```

And finally Access log

```
[08/Nov/2017:17:31:25 +0000] 127.0.0.1 - - - homeserv.mydomain.me  to: -: GET /sonarr/api/calendar?start=2017-10-09&end=2017-12-08 HTTP/1.1 upstream_response_time - msec 1510162285.533 request_time 90.001
[08/Nov/2017:17:31:39 +0000] 192.168.1.134 - - - homeserv.mydomain.me  to: -: GET /radarr HTTP/1.1 upstream_response_time - msec 1510162299.296 request_time 90.000
[08/Nov/2017:17:32:55 +0000] 127.0.0.1 - - - homeserv.mydomain.me  to: -: GET /sonarr/api/calendar?start=2017-10-09&end=2017-12-08 HTTP/1.1 upstream_response_time - msec 1510162375.845 request_time 90.001
[08/Nov/2017:17:33:34 +0000] 192.168.1.134 - - - homeserv.mydomain.me  to: -: GET /sonarr HTTP/1.1 upstream_response_time - msec 1510162414.407 request_time 90.000
[08/Nov/2017:17:34:26 +0000] 127.0.0.1 - - - homeserv.mydomain.me  to: -: GET /sonarr/api/calendar?start=2017-10-09&end=2017-12-08 HTTP/1.1 upstream_response_time - msec 1510162466.175 request_time 90.001
[08/Nov/2017:17:35:28 +0000] 192.168.1.134 - - - homeserv.mydomain.me  to: -: GET /jackett HTTP/1.1 upstream_response_time - msec 1510162528.996 request_time 90.000
[08/Nov/2017:17:35:56 +0000] 127.0.0.1 - - - homeserv.mydomain.me  to: -: GET /sonarr/api/calendar?start=2017-10-09&end=2017-12-08 HTTP/1.1 upstream_response_time - msec 1510162556.497 request_time 90.015
[08/Nov/2017:17:37:26 +0000] 127.0.0.1 - - - homeserv.mydomain.me  to: -: GET /sonarr/api/calendar?start=2017-10-09&end=2017-12-08 HTTP/1.1 upstream_response_time - msec 1510162646.825 request_time 90.000
[08/Nov/2017:17:38:41 +0000] 192.168.1.134 - - - homeserv.mydomain.me  to: -: GET /deluge HTTP/1.1 upstream_response_time - msec 1510162721.269 request_time 90.001
[08/Nov/2017:17:38:57 +0000] 127.0.0.1 - - - homeserv.mydomain.me  to: -: GET /sonarr/api/calendar?start=2017-10-09&end=2017-12-08 HTTP/1.1 upstream_response_time - msec 1510162737.113 request_time 90.002
[08/Nov/2017:17:40:27 +0000] 127.0.0.1 - - - homeserv.mydomain.me  to: -: GET /sonarr/api/calendar?start=2017-10-09&end=2017-12-08 HTTP/1.1 upstream_response_time - msec 1510162827.444 request_time 90.003
[08/Nov/2017:17:41:57 +0000] 127.0.0.1 - - - homeserv.mydomain.me  to: -: GET /sonarr/api/calendar?start=2017-10-09&end=2017-12-08 HTTP/1.1 upstream_response_time - msec 1510162917.770 request_time 90.014
[08/Nov/2017:17:43:28 +0000] 127.0.0.1 - - - homeserv.mydomain.me  to: -: GET /sonarr/api/calendar?start=2017-10-09&end=2017-12-08 HTTP/1.1 upstream_response_time - msec 1510163008.118 request_time 90.013
[08/Nov/2017:17:44:58 +0000] 127.0.0.1 - - - homeserv.mydomain.me  to: -: GET /sonarr/api/calendar?start=2017-10-09&end=2017-12-08 HTTP/1.1 upstream_response_time - msec 1510163098.517 request_time 90.008
[08/Nov/2017:17:46:28 +0000] 127.0.0.1 - - - homeserv.mydomain.me  to: -: GET /sonarr/api/calendar?start=2017-10-09&end=2017-12-08 HTTP/1.1 upstream_response_time - msec 1510163188.847 request_time 90.014
```

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
    location = /auth-admin {
    internal;
    proxy_pass http://homeserv.mydomain.me/auth.php?admin;
    proxy_pass_request_body off;
    proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
    proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
}
```

to:

```
location = /auth-admin{
    rewrite ^ /auth.php?admin;
}
```

Also, you should enable OPCache in php.

in php.ini: 
find: `[opcache]`

add this line after: `zend_extension=php_opcache.dll`

then make sure these values are set:

```
opcache.enable=1
opcache.memory_consumption=192
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=16
opcache.max_accelerated_files=10000
opcache.fast_shutdown=1
```

Also for shits and giggles edit php block and add blank location block:

```
    location / { }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
```

Comment: Just gave this a try and still seem to be getting the same issue, with the auth request enabled everything seems to time out at the php end but with it commented out it all works as intended? Logs give me the same errors as previously. (Also thanks for the awesome software, makes life so much easier than having to visit 8 different pages!)

Comment: jump on Discord later and we can narrow it down.  Thanks for the kind words too :)